# Access violation when sending WM_QUIT via PostThreadMessage

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, message-queue

I want to make a certain thread stop working. The thread function is as follows:

```
unsigned __stdcall keyloggingmanager::RunKeyLogger(void * args) {

    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(args);
    wcout << "RunKeyLogger Thread Started !" << endl;
    HINSTANCE appInstance = NULL;
    HHOOK _keyboardHook = NULL;
    appInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL); // getting the current module handle
    _keyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, ThisObj->KeyPressHandler, appInstance, GLOBAL_HOOK); // setting the hook.
    LPMSG msg = { 0 };
    while (GetMessage(msg, NULL, 0, 0) != 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(msg);
        DispatchMessage(msg);
    }

    cout << "Got WM_QUIT, aborting...\n";
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(_keyboardHook);
    if (_keyboardHook == NULL) {
        wcout << L"UNABLE TO HOOK" << endl; 
    }
    else if(appInstance == NULL)
    {
        wcout << L"UNABLE TO GET MODULE HANDLE" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

the line used to stop the thread is as follow:

```
PostThreadMessage(AboveThreadId, (UINT)WM_QUIT, NULL, NULL);
```

I get an access violation exception with this method.
I tried several variations, like:

```
while ( GetMessage(msg, hWnd, 0, 0) )
{
   if ( msg->message == WM_QUIT )
   {
       break;
   }
   else
   {
      TranslateMessage(&msg);
      DispatchMessage(&msg);
   } 
}
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Comment: I think WM_QUIT is meant to exit an application. I am not sure if there are any side effects. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632641(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: it says that this message causes the GetMessage function to return 0, which is my while condition. @Stefan

Comment: Use a debugger and/or post a minimal, verifiable and complete example.

Comment: If the code you posted is your actual code, you are passing a null pointer to `GetMessage()`. You need to point it to an actual real instance of a `MSG` structure.

Comment: Don't know whether that can cause an issue, but I noticed that you mixed `wcout` and `const char*` e.g. in `wcout << "RunKeyLogger ..."`

Comment: good insight :) is there any proper way you know to initial MSG structure ? @zenzelezz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LPMSG msg = { 0 };
```

This declares a pointer to a `MSG` structure. You then pass that pointer to `GetMessage`, but do not allocate an actual `MSG` structure for the pointer to point at.

Replace

```
LPMSG msg = { 0 };
```

with

```
MSG msg;
```

which allocates a `MSG` structure. Then call `GetMessage` like this

```
while ( GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) )
```

passing the address of that `MSG` structure.